# Is SonarQube messing up nullable boolean here?

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I have a piece of code like the one bellow and SonarQube is giving me this warning:
`Warning S2589: Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to 'true'.`

Is it possible that this is a false positive, or is my understanding of nullable boolean wrong?

Please note the warning is on the line starting with `else if`.

```
bool? isSaved = logSaver.Save("Some log message.");

if (isSaved.Equals(true))
{
    // Successfully saved.
}
else if (isSaved.Equals(false)) // <-- I get the warning here!
{
    // Could not be saved due to an error.
}
else
{
    // User canceled save operation -> do nothing.
}
```

A nullable boolean, as the name says, is a boolean which can also have `null` as a value. Just like `Boolean` class in Java.

---

To prove that `isSaved.Equals(...)` actually can return all three possible outcomes, please refer to this example:

```
bool? isSaved = null; // <- also try false and true!
System.Console.WriteLine(isSaved.Equals(null));
System.Console.WriteLine(isSaved.Equals(true));
System.Console.WriteLine(isSaved.Equals(false));
```

The output is:

```
True
False
False
```

Comment: Can `logSaver.Save` actually ever return `null`, never mind the actual type? SQ might just be more clever than you think. If it *can* return `null`, it's definitely incorrect to flag this. (That said, do consider something like `enum SaveResult { NotSaved, Saved, Cancelled }` as a clearer alternative to a tri-state boolean; the semantics make them a bit icky.)

Comment: Good point. But this method has the following signature in the `interface`: `bool? Save(string logMessages);`. But not only that, even the implementing methods actually do return `null`.

Comment: Look at the definition of Boolean.Equals; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean.equals?view=net-6.0    "true if obj is a Boolean and has the same value as this instance; otherwise, false."

Comment: @JayBuckman: which is not relevant here, since we're using `Nullable<Boolean>.Equals`. The third branch of the conditional is definitely reachable.

Comment: A wild shot in the dark and notwithstanding that SQ is in the wrong here, but if you have a recent version of C#, see if it likes `isSaved is true` and `isSaved is false` better (pattern matching). With recent versions of the runtime, this actually compiles to better code as well, and is arguably (but subjectively) a bit clearer even than `==`.

Comment: Nice idea but SonarQube detects it again (same warning). Using .NET 4.7.2.

Comment: Time to fire up the old browser for a bug report then, methinks (assuming you have the latest version of SQ). Nullable booleans may not be pretty, but the analyzer should still handle them properly, regardless of how they're tested.

Comment: Please paste the link of the issue report here or add it to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, sorry for the confusion, I meant -- time for *you* to fire up the old browser. :) I'm not an active SQ user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead :

```csharp
if (isSaved.HasValue && isSaved.Value)
{
    // Successfully saved.
}
else if (isSaved.HasValue && !isSaved.Value)
{
    // Could not be saved due to an error.
}
else
{
    // User canceled save operation -> do nothing.
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't try to clarify your code for a plugin when it clearly doesn't recognize all possible values properly by itself. That is avoidable complexity.